# How to set background - image for whole Bootstrap container-fluid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to replicate Paypal's navbar and section below it for training purposes.
I've created one container-fluid and two rows within it.
I've set background-image of this container but ... it covers only one of two rows it should, why ?

```css
.container fluid {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url('https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/mktg/wright/home/homepage-hero-1x.jpg');
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="https://www.seeklogo.net/?p=72581" target="_blank"><img id="pp"src="https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/paypal-logo-preview-400x400.png"  alt="PayPal logo vector" /></a> 
    </div
    
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <ul>
        <li>PERSONAL <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        <li>BUSINESS  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        <li>PARTNERS & DEVELOPERS</li>
      </ul>
      
      <button  id="login"class="buttons" type="btn">Log in</button>
      <button id="signup"class="buttons"type="btn">Sign up</button> 
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="row2">
      <h1>The simpler, safer way to<br>pay and get paid.</h1>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/zeeebra/pen/MvYOwj?editors=1100

Comment: Seems to work fine...

Comment: the code in that codepen is different from what you posted here. And in the code here, `row2` is  a child of `row1`. And the closing `</div>  in line 6 of the HTML code is missing a `>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give a fixed image in the background that does not move while scrolling. Try the following code.

```
.box{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(1.jpg);
}
```

Just replace the image name. I hope this helps!